# generic method and anonymous types

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Would it be possible to create code like this:

```
private static string GetInsertString<TDto>()
{
    var type = typeof(TDto);
    var properties = type.GetProperties().Where(Where);
    var tableName = type.Name;

    return string.Format("INSERT INTO {0} ({1}) VALUES ({2});", 
    tableName, 
    string.Join(",", properties.Select(x => x.Name).ToArray()),
    string.Join(",", properties.Select(x => string.Format("@{0}", x.Name.ToLower())).ToArray()));
}
```

that works with anonymous types like this:

```
var point = new { X = 13, Y = 7 };
```

PS:

Output would be:

```
INSERT INTO Anonymous (X, Y) values (13, 7)
```

of course you may want to provide the table name.

Comment: Which values would you want inside the anonymous type

Comment: It would be nice to see your expected output.

Comment: as you said the type is "anonymous" - so of course there is no value for `TDto`) for the compiler to resolve (of course there IS a type but no way to get it). - Just change it to something like `string  GetInsertString(object o) { var type = o.GetType(); ... }` - not as neat but it should work this way (call it with a example of your an. type)

Comment: @khellang I have updated the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using .net 4.0 or above, you can use dynamic and `ExpandoObject` like this:

```
private static string GetInsertString(dynamic obj)
{
    var expando = (ExpandoObject)obj;

    return string.Format("INSERT INTO {0} ({1}) VALUES ({2});",
        "tableName",
        string.Join(",", expando.Select(x => x.Key)),
        string.Join(",", expando.Select(x => x.Value is string ? "'" + x.Value + "'" : x.Value.ToString())));
}
```

And then:

```
dynamic o = new ExpandoObject();

o.a = 10;
o.b = "hello";

var s = GetInsertString(o);
```

Now `s` is `INSERT INTO tableName (a,b) VALUES (10,'hello');`.
This is only a draft you have to do some work to get a correct `insert` string.

Comment: Yeah use .net 4.0 and I recently learned about the existence of the ExpandoObject. Looks great thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You won't be able to specify the type parameter with an anonymous type, but if you pass it an object as a parameter, you can use type inference to get a hold of the type:

```
private static string GetInsertString<TDto>(TDto dto)
{
    var type = typeof(TDto);
    var propertyNames = type.GetProperties().Where(Where).Select(x => x.Name);

    return string.Format("INSERT INTO {0} ({1}) VALUES ({2});",
        type.Name,
        string.Join(",", propertyNames),
        string.Join(",", propertyNames.Select(x => string.Format("@{0}", x.ToLower())));
}
```

Then call the method: `var insertString = GetInsertString(new { X = 13, Y = 7 });`

Comment: This will work though it is worth explicitly mentioning that `type.Name` will be something like `<>f__AnonymousType0\`2` which is not very nice...

Answer (score 3):

It is very hard to use anonymous types with a `...<T>()` method. The main way of doing that involves the *by example* hack, i.e.

```
var dummy = new { X = 13, Y = 7 };
Foo(dummy); // for Foo<T>(T obj)
```

or more succinctly:

```
Foo(new { X = 13, Y = 7 });
```

which uses generic type inference to deduce that `T` here is the anonymous type. `Foo<T>(T obj)` could *either* be your actual method, or could be a method that in turn *calls* `GetInsertString<TDto>()`, i.e.

```
// overload that takes an example object as a parameter
private static string GetInsertString<TDto>(TDto example) {
    return GetInsertString<TDto>();
}
```

You could also probably combine the two:

```
private static string GetInsertString<TDto>(TDto example = null) {
    .. your code ..
}
```

and pass the example only when it is necessary.

However, the "by example" approach is brittle and susceptible to breaking. I strongly recommend that you simply define a POCO instead:

```
public class MyType {
    public int X {get;set;}
    public int Y {get;set;}
}
```

and use `GetInsertString<MyType>`.

Comment: Thanks Marc. The reason I investigate anonymous types is because the data is dynamic (e.g potentially coming from a List<Dictionary<string,object>>) - hence there is no chance of using a POCO.

Comment: @csetzkorn a `Dictionary<string,object>`, however, is nothing at all like an anonymous type, and would require very different handling

Comment: I know - I was thinking of transforming it into an anonymous type but maybe I can just handle it directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use anonymous objects with generic methods as long as the compiler can resolve the type. For instance, if it can be resolved from a parameter. Like this:

```
private static string GetInsertString<TDto>(TDto someObject) {
    var type = typeof(TDto);
    var properties = type.GetProperties();  // Removed .Where(Where) since it didn't compile
    var tableName = type.Name;

    return string.Format(
        "INSERT INTO {0} ({1}) VALUES ({2});", 
        tableName, 
        string.Join(",", properties.Select(x => x.Name).ToArray()),
        string.Join(",", properties.Select(x => string.Format("@{0}", x.Name.ToLower())).ToArray())
    );
}

var point = new { X = 13, Y = 7 };
var insertSql = Test.GetInsertString(point);
// Results in: INSERT INTO <>f__AnonymousType0`2 (X,Y) VALUES (@x,@y);
```